# Implementing inequality join in Hive

Tags: join, hive, hiveql

I have two tables with ids. A smaller table has ids to exclude from the larger table. 
How do I implement this in Hive?

If I have to use transform, can you help me with the script?

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have two tables like below:

Table a:
id
1
2
3

Table b:
id
2
3

Desired output Table:
id
1

The query below should work.

```
select a.id from a left outer join b on (a.id==b.id) where b.id is null
```

Comment: We can make above query even shorter - `select a.id from a left outer join b on (a.id==b.id) where b.id is null`

Comment: That's even better. I modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the small table is small enough to fit into memory, try using the `distributed_map` UDF from Brickhouse ( http://github.com/klout/brickhouse ) .  Insert your keys into a local directory, and then send that local directory into the distributed cache.  Then you can access the contents of the map from your Hive query.

```
insert overwrite local directory 'exclude_ids' 
   select id, value from small_table;

add file exclude_id;

select * from big_table
where map_index( distributed_map( 'exclude_ids' ), id ) = null;
```

If the small table is too big to fit into memory, and you have access to an HBase server, try the `hbase_cached_get` UDF to do something similar.